# mysql populate a field of a content?

Tags: 7, nodes, database

I have a content type that has the field field_data_latitude.  I see in the database the existence of a table called field_data_field_latitude that contains the values for this content type .  When I populate it via mysql, the value does not show up in the CMS.  Are there other tables I'm supposed to populate?

I also noticed a table called field_data_field_latitude..I popualted that as well but the value is not visible in the CMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear the cache after adding your custom values to the database.  Might fix the problem as I have seen it work for some in the past.